# Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr 0x74446000 in tid 13424 (GLThread 785)

Tags: opengl-es

I'm getting this error Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr 0x74446000 in tid 13424 (GLThread 785) when I run in Nexus 9.
But other cellphone doesn't crash(HTC Butterfly2,Samsung note3).
When I run in Debug,it run in gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES,0,vCount); will crash.

Here is my code

```
public void drawSelf(GL10 gl)
{
    gl.glRotatef(mAngleZ, 0, 0, 1);
    gl.glRotatef(mAngleX, 1, 0, 0);
    gl.glRotatef(mAngleY, 0, 1, 0);

    //允許使用頂點陣列
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    gl.glVertexPointer
    (
            3,              
            GL10.GL_FIXED,  
            0,              
            mVertexBuffer   
    );
    mVertexBuffer.rewind();


    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);

    gl.glNormalPointer(GL10.GL_FIXED, 0, mNormalBuffer);
    mNormalBuffer.rewind();
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);     
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY); 

    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);   

    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, mTextureBuffer);
    mTextureBuffer.rewind();

    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId);

    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES,0,vCount);

}
```

And here is my logcat says:

```html
07-26 20:28:57.879: A/libc(13361): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr 0x74446000 in tid 13424 (GLThread 785)
07-26 20:28:57.910: E/WifiStateMachine(453): WifiStateMachine CMD_START_SCAN source -2 txSuccessRate=2.17 rxSuccessRate=0.17 targetRoamBSSID=any RSSI=-70
07-26 20:28:57.910: E/WifiStateMachine(453): WifiStateMachine starting scan for "Adam"WPA_PSK with 2437
07-26 20:28:58.003: I/DEBUG(13125): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
07-26 20:28:58.003: I/DEBUG(13125): Build fingerprint: 'google/volantis/flounder:5.1.1/LMY47X/1849464:user/release-keys'
07-26 20:28:58.003: I/DEBUG(13125): Revision: '0'
07-26 20:28:58.003: I/DEBUG(13125): ABI: 'arm64'
07-26 20:28:58.004: I/DEBUG(13125): pid: 13361, tid: 13424, name: GLThread 785  >>> com.example.holophyr <<<
07-26 20:28:58.004: I/DEBUG(13125): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0x74446000
07-26 20:28:58.023: I/DEBUG(13125):     x0   0000007f90b97fd0  x1   0000000074446000  x2   0000000000000010  x3   0000000000000c00
07-26 20:28:58.023: I/DEBUG(13125):     x4   0000007f90b9f9a0  x5   0000000000000000  x6   0000000000000463  x7   0000000000000000
07-26 20:28:58.023: I/DEBUG(13125):     x8   0000000000000000  x9   0000000000000000  x10  8000000409a20000  x11  0000000000000000
07-26 20:28:58.023: I/DEBUG(13125):     x12  0000000000000004  x13  0000007f90b97fd0  x14  000000000000000c  x15  0000000000000006
07-26 20:28:58.023: I/DEBUG(13125):     x16  0000000000000004  x17  0000000409a66fd0  x18  0000007f9c696000  x19  0000007f9164b8ac
07-26 20:28:58.024: I/DEBUG(13125):     x20  000000000000010d  x21  0000000000000c00  x22  0000007f90b97fd0  x23  0000007f91b16820
```

Please help me,and I'm so sorry my english poor.

Comment: You cannot expect that the code will work properly while you mix calls to GLES 1.0 and GLES 2.0 APIs in the same program!

Comment: But...my cellphone Butterfiy2 can work.On the Internet,someone said many Nexus users have this problem.Maybe the problem lies in the RAM??