# android Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x9 in tid 27173

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-android

I am new to cocos creator. I am working on a game and when i press home button and get back to app. then app is crashed. shows this error while debugging.

android Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x9 in tid 27173 (GLThread 1836)

Already searched a lot. But i dont understand what to do.
tried

[Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr 0x74446000 in tid 13424 (GLThread 785)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31638366/6891563)

[Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x48 in tid 21741 (RenderThread) in android in rear case in some device](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42966459/6891563)

If someone can explain me in simple words what to do. 
Thanks in advance.